# tr won't be appended

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an empty table which i want to fill with tds when i press a button.I want to create a new tr after every 3 tds.
I have the following code:

```
var ruler=0;
    var start=false;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").on("click",function(){
            if (start === false){$("table").append("<tr>"); start = true;}
            if(ruler === 3){
                $("table").append("</tr><tr>");
                ruler = 0;
            }
            $("table tr").append("<td>mama</td>");
            ruler++;
        });
    });
```

html

```
 <table>
 </table>
```

The problem is that even after changing row it will continue adding tds in the first line.Any ideas?

Comment: `$("table tr")` selects all `tr` elements on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Teemu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1169519/teemu) stated you are **selecting all** `<tr>`. So I added a [:last selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/).

```js
    var ruler = 0;
    var start = false;
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("button").on("click", function() {
        if (start === false) {
          $("table").append("<tr>");
          start = true;
        }
        if (ruler === 3) {
          $("table").append("</tr><tr>");
          ruler = 0;
        }
        $("table tr:last").append("<td>mama</td>");
        ruler++;
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
<table></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use table tr:last as a selector to make sure for the application to append the content to the last row.